# mysql query to remove space after last comma in string

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with data like this.

```
Fullname
Adarna , Neil.
David , Jundemil.
```

I want to remove all spaces between lastname and the comma

so the data looks like this.

```
Adarna, Neil.
David, Jundemil.
```

tried this query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fullname`, ' ,', 2) from tbl_users
```

output was all fullname with commas

Comment: So what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: try `select replace(fullname,' ,','') ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try as per below-

```
update mytable set fullname = replace(fullname,' ,',',');
```